# Why are there different definitions of symbolism?

Tags: american-english

Some commonly accepted symbolism: Wall Street-wealth, dove-peace. This is said to be correct at least by my teacher.

I know that symbolism is basically using a physical thing to represent a less physical /abstract thing, like ldea.

Is this the reason why my teacher didn't accept it when I wrote, president obama-racial equality on a presidential level?

Comment: "pres obama" is a great symbol of "racial equality".  (or perhaps "racial equality in america", say).  your phrase: "racial equality on a presidential level" is sort of confused and doesn't mean much.

Answer (score 0):

Symbol: a **mark or character** used as a **conventional representation** of an object, function, or process, e.g. the letter or letters standing for a chemical element or a character in musical notation.

This is what google produced when I entered 'Define symbol'.

Symbolism, very simply put, is using something to illustrate an abstract concept. I think your mistake was in using president Obama to illustrate racial equality and calling that usage 'symbolism'. This usage is more like personification or epitomization and could be re-constructed in a better way to bring out the essence of personification.
For ex: 'We know that president Obama is an embodiment of racial equality.'
Hope that helped!

Comment: "is using a non-living thing".  Nah.  it is extremely commonplace to say such-and-such person is a symbol of such-and-such.

Comment: True. I just realized that there are instances where people are also used as symbols. But again, I think that kind of symbolism would be better known as a metaphor or a personification. That's what I found out in the little research that I did on this matter. Do let me know if I'm wrong.

Comment: people are completely commonly used as symbols. this has utterly no connection at all to "personification" or "metaphor".